# Limit gradle transitivty depth resolution

Tags: gradle

I'm trying to solve an issue about transitivity with gradle. In my project, I have a huge tree caused by several modules of my own which are build independantly

I would like to be able to limit the transitivy to a depth. Because I do not want to exclude manually each dependency...

In the documentation it's nearly only about substitution.

How can I achived this ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Normally, if a dependency is declared, that is for a reason.

Comment: Agree with the theory, but in my context this is a problem.

Comment: Could you explain this context?

Comment: Very complex to do via text. Let's say that we have multiple layers of dependencies (internal / external ) with open source that we do not want to use directly. We may have conflict between some dependencies version at lowest level and we want to handle ourselves (and force it). But we have also a top level projet who depends on child dependencies (ours) and we would like to get first child dependencies of theses childs of our own.